# Error 500 ONLY in dashboard main page. How to fix it?

Tags: apache

I receive a 500 server error ONLY in the main dashboard of a WordPress based website.

All the front-end is working properly as well as any other page in the admin area. It's just the main WordPress admin dashboard which gives this error. And since after logging in you're always redirected there it's very annoying for my client...

I've already tried multiple solutions without success:

- disable all the plugins
- start with a clean .htaccess
- re-upload WordPress core files
- increase the memory limit in the php.ini file

Any other idea to fix this problem? Is there a way to disable the main dashboard and maybe send the logged user directly to the article's list?

FYI: This is the list on plugins I'm using right now:

- Advanced Custom Fields: Repeater Field   1.1.1
- Advanced Custom Fields   4.3.9
- Ajax Load More: Custom Repeaters 1.3
- Ajax Load More   2.2.3
- All In One WP Security   v3.8.4
- Disqus Comment System    2.77
- Manual Image Crop    1.08
- NextGEN Plus by Photocrati   1.0
- NextGEN Gallery by Photocrati    2.0.66.29
- Ozh' Tweet Archiver  2.0.2
- Revolution Slider    4.6.0
- Safe Redirect Manager    1.7.5
- WPML Multilingual CMS    3.1.8
- Types - Complete Solution for Custom Fields and Types    1.6.3
- WordPress SEO    1.6.3
- wp-days-ago  3.0.4.2
- WP No Base Permalink 0.2.2
- WPML Media   2.1.7
- WPML String Translation  2.0.10
- WPML Translation Management  1.9.7

Comment: first step is to check for php errors at the error log file. If there is no such thing start turning off plugins....

Comment: Thanks, I just discovered it was a problem with file permissions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered it was a problem with file permissions.

This [article](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/05/08/proper-wordpress-filesystem-permissions-ownerships/) on Smashing Magazine is helpful to understand how to set up correct permissions.

Comment: that link may not be there in the future. So your answer will be more helpful if you described what exactly you have done to resolve the issue.